# Is there a more efficient way to find the index of the end of a substring?

Tags: vb.net, substring, console-application, text-extraction

I'm reading an XML tag to try and extract a value from it:

```
<lsource xml:lang="por">
```

I want to extract the three letter code `por`. There might be other attributes in the tag, so my current approach is to find the index of the substring `xml:lang=`, then add 11 to it. It works just fine, I'm just wondering if there's another more intuitive or more efficient solution.

Code:

```
If initialTag.Contains("xml:lang") Then
    Dim langCodePos As Integer = line.IndexOf("xml:lang=") + 11
    lsource.LanguageCode = Mid(line, langCodePos, 3)
End If
```

Comment: `lsource.LanguageCode = XElement.Parse(initialTag).@xml:lang`?

Comment: Perfect, works a charm! If you post that as an answer I can accept :)

Comment: Actually I [don't think](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) you should use this isolated line of code. Rather, process the XML as XML in the first place instead of parsing it or parts of it as strings.

Comment: I could, but I don't know how to parse XML, so I've already made a parser that simply reads the tags and does a lot of Select Cases. I would have to learn how to parse XML and redo the whole thing, whereas this solution works for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim xml = XDocument.Load("xml.xml")
MsgBox(xml.<tag>.<tag2>.<lsource>(0).FirstAttribute.Value)
```

You have to esplicit all the tags... I'm not sure is what you are looking for... Tell me